# What is the difference between ‘interest in' & ‘interest for' ?

Tags: prepositions

When I should use 'for' after the noun 'interest' & when 'in' should be used after that?

For example, is it correct to say "I have no interest for drug"?

If you can give an elucidation with example, it will be better for me to understand.

Comment: By way of contrast: "taste" "desire" "lust" and "need" all can take "for". Thus: no taste for drugs, no desire for drugs, no lust for drugs, no need for drugs.

Answer (score 11):

In most of the cases, you are generally ***interested in....*** something. The word here serves as an *adjective*.

As Jason says,

> *I am not **interested in** drugs OR I am very **interested in history***

However, ***'interest for...'*** is **not** incorrect! But it's used differently. It then becomes a *noun*.

> *This museum holds particular **interest for** geologists.*

Answer (score 8):

With interest as a noun meaning something that draws or holds one's attention, **in** is generally used to specify the **object of the interest**:

> Almost fifty years after the end of the Second World War, scholarly interest **in its history** appears to be as vigorous as ever. [Soviet Military Deception in the Second World War](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=QZgZfvuAk3sC&pg=PR31&dq=%22interest%20in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHmMqKoOfZAhVDqaQKHSHmDU04ZBDoAQhPMAc#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20in%22&f=false)

**in** can also be used to specify a time period:

As it can be seen, only seven elements (As, Br, Cr, Hg, I, Se and V) were of interest **in the last few years**. [Handbook of mineral elements in food](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=ofLEBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA254&dq=%22interest%20in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHmMqKoOfZAhVDqaQKHSHmDU04ZBDoAQgyMAI#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20in%22&f=false)

and also to specify a location:

> Exclusion from school has excited a great deal of research interest **in England** during the 1990s. [Combating social exclusion through education](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=9bYxrIfTPTYC&pg=PA69&dq=%22interest%20in%20england%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj27eTpoefZAhVDyaQKHcRZAWk4KBDoAQgsMAE#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20in%20england%22&f=false)

**for** is much less widely used, and generally specifies **who is interested** in something:

> ...the 2011 Commission Decision is of great interest **for social services**... [Financing Services of General Economic Interest](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=Tqn3v5TKL1wC&pg=PA183&dq=%22interest%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6gPaAo-fZAhXL2qQKHQ1zDmM4qgEQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20for%22&f=false)

It could also be used to specify a time period

> The equation of state (EOS) of dense hydrogen has been a subject of great interest **for years** because of its astrophysical importance and its theoretical novelty. [The Link Foundation Energy Fellowship Program](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=bjlkWoodlRkC&pg=PA135&dq=%22interest%20for%20years%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnyZr_o-fZAhXGzKQKHXe2Bmk4KBDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20for%20years%22&f=false)

You cannot use **for** to identify the object of interest

> I have no interest **for drugs** - *wrong*

but you could turn it round to specify who is interested

> Drugs have no interest **for me**

Comment: A very well written answer! Incidentally, what would you say about this example? "Various members of the committee indicated an interest for more color on the buildings." https://www.dailycal.org/2021/07/18/berkeley-design-review-committee-discusses-design-proposals-for-3-projects/ Contamination?

Comment: @AlexB. Understandable, but sounds not quite right, because it doesn't use one of the standard usages of the word **for**.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for

Answer (score 0):

9 out of 10 times you should use "interest in."  I've heard "interest for" only a few times.  The only examples I can think of would be "This credit card account will accumulate 13% interest for the first six months," or "The new discovery holds interest for scientists." In both of these cases, interest has a completely different meaning.  In cases like "I have no interest in that thing" or "She showed signs of interest in me," always use "interest in."

Comment: Saying that "interest" has a completely different meaning in the situations where "interest for" is correct, but not explaining that meaning misses the point of the question. The question is "what's the difference ?"

Comment: In the first example, interest on a credit card refers to additional payment on a loan.  In the second, interest for scientists means it holds a certain appeal or allure for the scientists.  It's different from interest in; with interest in, the the object (the word after "in") is the thing that is interesting, while with interest for, the subject is the thing that is interesting.

Comment: Why are you putting that information in a comment instead of incorporating it into your answer?